# limit the output of a command in a terminal based on lines displayable

Tags: shell, terminal

Given an alias that lists last modified files, like this:

> alias lt='ls -ltc|head -10'

is there a way to determine the lines displayable so I could have a filter/limit that is a function of that.

Not concerned about other issues like line-wrapping etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of lines displayable on the current terminal is available in the `$LINES` variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the terminal's size with:

```
stty size
```

which responds with number of rows and columns, e.g.:

> 25 80

And

```
stty size | awk '{print $1;}'
```

would give you just the number of lines.